# Non-Overlapping Sliding Window Sum of 3D Matrix

Tags: matlab, sum, window

I am running into some difficulty with the following situation:

I have a 3D matrix called 'ch'. I would like to sum in the z direction in groups of 5 matrices and save them to a different matrix, 'ch_sample' e.g. ch_sample(:,:,1) = ch(:,:,1) + ch(:,:,2) ... + ch(:,:,5) ; ch_sample(:,:,2) = ch(:,:,6) + ch(:,:,7) ... + ch(:,:,10) etc.

Thus, I would like to get a non-overlapping sliding window (size = 5) to take sums in the z direction of my matrix. I need to preserve the x and y coordinates of values in ch.

I have tried accomplishing this via for loops and failed.

Any suggestions and comments are welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you dont need explicit for loops for this simple task. Second, to make it efficient for big matrices, use helper matrix:

```
clear

NumToSum = 5; 

M = randi([0,9],[4,3,10]); %our matrix
cumsumM = cumsum(M,3); %helper matrix. cumulative sum in 3rd dimension
R0 = cumsumM(:,:,1:NumToSum);
R1 = cumsumM(:,:,NumToSum+1:end) - cumsumM(:,:,1:end-NumToSum);
R=cat(3,R0,R1); %the result

disp([M,R]) %display side by side
```

Answer (score 0):

Here [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) can be used to get the result:

```
group_size = 5;
s = size(ch);
grp = reshape(ch, s(1)*s(2), group_size, []);    % reshape to form groups
sumgrp = sum(grp, 2);                            % sum of each group calculated
ch_sample = reshape(sumgrp, s(1), s(2),[]);      % reshape back to original dimensions
```

All in one:

```
ch_sample = reshape(sum(reshape(ch, s(1)*s(2), group_size, []), 2), s(1), s(2),[]);
```

*Note: `reshape` is a very cheap operation.